# How to make a scrollable Jpanel inside a JTabbedPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane

I'm trying to make a `JFrame` that contains a `JTabbedPane`. There are 3 tabs and each tab has a panel inside it. The first panel (aka first tab) must have 3 elements positioned *vertically*: a `JLabel`, a picture and a text area. The tabs must be always visible at the top while the contents of the tab can be scrolled through. No matter what I tried (windowbuilder, other Stackoverflow answers) I just can't seem to make this work.

Comment: Have you tried using JScrollPane?

Comment: It will be difficult to know what you've done wrong or what incorrect assumptions you may have without code, preferably a minimal example program. Else, you're asking us to re-write the [JScrollPane tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), and why do that when an excellent one already exists?

Comment: I gave you an example in answer below, but be free to post some code for more relevant solution (posted only example).

Answer (score 4):

Without any code you have tried, I can give you some example.

```
    // Tabbed pane
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    contentPane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // First panel
    JPanel pan1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));

    // Content of First panel
    JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Test1");
    pan1.add(lbl1);

    JTextField textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setColumns(10);
    pan1.add(textField_3);

    JTextField  textField_4 = new JTextField();
    textField_4.setColumns(10);
    pan1.add(textField_4);
    // Second panel
    JPanel pan2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    // Content of Second panel
    JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Test2");
    pan2.add(lbl2);
    // First Scroll pane
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(pan1);
    // Second Scroll pane
    JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(pan2);

    tabbedPane.add("Tab1", scrollPane1);
    tabbedPane.add("Tab2", scrollPane2);
```

Change panel's content with labels, pictures etc. Change their layout, too. If you provide some code, I can give you exact solution.

Comment: `pan1.setLayout(null);` is possible one of the worst suggestions you can  make.  It will effect the `JScrollPane`'s ability to calculate the amount of space that the component requires and show it's scroll bars if required

Comment: Get rid of the `setBounds`, they are irrelevant under the management of the layouts and just generate noise/confusion ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of options...

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).

## You could...

Place the `JScrollPane` directly under a tab...

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = ...
JPanel theView = ...
// Place the elements you want to show on the panel...

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(theView);
tabbedPane.add("Tab with scroll pane", scrollPane);
```

## You could...

Place the scroll pane within another container and add that to the tabbed pane...

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = ...
JPanel theView = ...
// Place the elements you want to show on the panel...

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(theView);
JPanel tabPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // As an example layout
tabPane.add(scrollPane);

tabbedPane.add("Tab with panel with scroll pane", tabPane);
```

Basically, a `JScrollPane` is just another component/container, which allows it to be used any where other components/containers can be used.